# default ngOptions on parent/child models AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I assign default `ngOptions` through parent/child models?

**[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700734/switching-data-models-in-angularjs-for-dynamic-select-menus/17701334)**  OP shows a way form parent/child relationships using `ngOptions`

**template**

```
<select ng-model="x.site" ng-options="s.site for s in data"></select>
<select ng-model="x.name" ng-options="b.name for b in x.site.buildings"></select>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.x = {};
$scope.data = [
    {
        "site" : "Brands Hatch",
        "buildings" : [
            { "name" : "Building #1" },
            { "name" : "Building #2" },
            { "name" : "Building #3" }
        ]
    },{
        "site" : "Silverstone",
        "buildings" : [
            { "name" : "Building #4" },
            { "name" : "Building #5" },
            { "name" : "Building #6" }
        ]
    }
];
```

What you will see in **[this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/7Kzgr/)** is that the dropdowns do not have any default values --- That is, the default option is "*blank*". In a normal use case this is a non issue, and default options are easily configurable through the controller which is explained well **[in the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select#Example)**.

- How do I eliminate "blank" options for parent/child models using `ngOptions`?
- How do I select default options either **through the view** or **dynamically through the controller**. *It's important to remember here that the child default select options are first dependant on the parents selected option.*

Comment: Updated my answer, the initial value was not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blank item is caused by the empty model value. You can try to put the following code at the end of the controller. The trick is to initialize *site*, *building* and *floor* when the page is loaded as well as when the *site* value is changed. Hope it helps.

```
$scope.selected = {
    site: $scope.data[0],
    building: $scope.data[0].buildings[0],
    floor: $scope.data[0].floors[0]
};

$scope.$watch('selected.site', function () {
    console.log($scope.selected.site);
    $scope.selected = {
        site: $scope.selected.site,
        building: $scope.selected.site.buildings[0],
        floor: $scope.selected.site.floors[0]
    };
});
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way to solve this problem without declaring local models at all?... Even if it means changing the way the parent/child relationship is formed or the directives are used differently. It seems really dirty to explicitly declare an index.

Comment: I will think about it. It seems Angularjs binds the data anyway using  ng-model for each ddl, maybe you can try to reinvent the `select` directive. Your question is great btw :)

Comment: @DanKanze I just saw this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select) and it seems the solution is just simply give the initial value of the model.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also particularly interested how to solve this problem with async data... I'm running into a senario where I have to wrap this solution in a callback --- because the local model cant get set on an index that hasnt yet been declared and becomes `undefined`.

Comment: @DanKanze I think you can create factory method and return `promise` so you can add the callback in the controller by chaining the `promise`